# How to read a Python marshal-written file in C#?

Tags: c#, python, serialization, marshalling

I'm working on converting a markov-chain chatbot from Python to C# for some friends, but am having a bit of difficulty with a language feature of Python that I have not encountered before. The bot is built off of pyborg, https://github.com/bdrewery/PyBorg.

Part of the initialization of this bot is reading from a words.dat and lines.dat file to populate dictionaries, like so:

```
content = self.read_file("words.dat")
self.words = marshal.loads(content)
del content
content = self.read_file("lines.dat")
self.lines = marshal.loads(content)
del content
```

Both of these files are full of the results of a call to "marshal.dumps" with large dictionary objects passed in as the arguments like so:

```
f = open("words.dat", "wb")
s = marshal.dumps(self.words)
f.write(s)
f.close()
f = open("lines.dat", "wb")
s = marshal.dumps(self.lines)
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

From what I've been able to gather, the Python "marshal" module is responsible for a type of serialization, in which objects are converted into a byte representation "specific to Python." https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html

I expect these files to be full of key/value sets, but I haven't been able to find any information on how to convert from this "marshal" byte set to something I can parse as string, List, or Dictionary objects in C#. Is there a way to do so without executing external Python scripts from my application?

Comment: The marshal module is not designed to be parsed by external tools as stated in the docs. Choosing it for persistence was IMHO a bad design choice of the authors. You might be able to convert the files to something more useful using a Python script but outside of the Python world it will be next to impossible to retrieve the data. Even with the wrong Python version you will have troubles.

Comment: What I'd do is write my own load and dump routines in c# for a fairly standard / understandable format, e.g. csv or fixed width. Then write a simple script in python to load and marshal the source / input files (as per the code above) and then save them in your .csv format.  Then you can ditch the marshal'd files completely.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree that continuing to rely on the marshal module is a recipe for disaster. I'll try to extract and serialize the files as something more C#-friendly with Python, that seems a much more approachable path than getting C# to correctly parse the current .dats. Thanks guys.